# Spring context initialization failed

Tags: spring

```
2014-05-27 08:47:55,170 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader]    (ContextLoader.java:319) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-security.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/app-ws-client.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 46 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-security.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'wsdl:tExtensibilityElement' to a(n) 'type definition' component.**
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:246)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:182)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 46 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-security.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'wsdl:tExtensibilityElement' to a(n) 'type definition' component.****
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
at
```

Can anyone please provide your input to know cause and solution of this issue.

we have app-ws-client.xml, that gets loaded when application starts.  app-ws-client.xml have below code

`<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-security.xml" />
   <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http.xml" />`

Spring context takes care of loading these. and it starts complaining to load cxf-extension-security.xml  This code is there since many years... we started facing this issue with just a restart.  No changes were done to app-ws-client.xml.

Comment: This is just a bunch of error messages... what about providing some context of its usage? How did it come to this?

Comment: You should show your `/cxf-extension-security.xml` to determine what `wsdl:tExtensibilityElement`means

Comment: Edited description, hope it helps.  we donot have visibility to cxf-extension-security.xml.  app-ws-client.xml code:  
`<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">`  import resource should be getting it from cxf.apache.org/schemas

Comment: @Werner Please advise

Comment: @ArtemBilan please advice

Comment: You should open `cxf.jar` find file `cxf-extension-security.xml` and show its content here. Looks like it is corrupted

Comment: "No changes were done to app-ws-client.xml", so what else may have changed? Some SAX library version? The JVM with its own SAX parser?

Comment: @Werner We have following cxf jars, and **in NONE** i could find `cxf-extension-security.xml` 
cxf-api-2.0.3.2-fuse.jar
cxf-common-schemas-2.0.3.2-fuse.jar
cxf-common-utilities-2.0.3.2-fuse.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.0.3.2-fuse.jar
cxf-rt-core-2.0.3.2-fuse.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.0.3.2-fuse.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.0.3.2-fuse.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.0.3.2-fuse.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-2.0.3.2-fuse.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-2.0.3.2-fuse.jar
cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.0.3.2-fuse.jar
cxf-rt-ws-security-2.0.3.2-fuse.jar
cxf-tools-common-2.0.3.2-fuse.jar

Comment: @ArneBurmeister application specific properties file(system.properties) were changed to modify a text, which is very common and restarted, and that is when application didn't come and shows up above error. Strange thing is, this works in my local desktop windows environment, but not in linux servers.

Comment: issue was with proxy server. Issue got resolved by passing these parameter to tomcat server... Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy sername> -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080